# Hiding content for mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, browser

I have 2 divs that I am trying to hide for mobile/tablet browsers.
To do this, I have included a separate stylsheet:

In the stylesheet I just put display: none on those divs but this doesn't seem to be working.
The demo site is over at www.thewestharbour.com/mypakage

We use WPTouch Pro for mobile and I also tried just adding the custom classes to their theme stylesheet but that was a no go either.

Answer (score 0):

Change `max-device-width` to `max-width` in the media attribute.

Since you are setting `width=device-width` in the viewport meta tag, the width is now configured to be the right number on mobile, whereas on desktops you will be targeting the window size.

AKA: device-width on desktop browsers is not the window size.

Comment: Hmm this makes sense but those divs are still showing up on my iPhone

Comment: @WadeDOuellet Hmmm, you might try adding `initial-scale=1.0` to the meta tag but I doubt it'll help.

Comment: Still no go on that, I just updated the original post with some more details